# How can we position an image obtained from an image sprite?

Tags: html, css

The question is that how to position an image obtained from an image sprite, since background-position property has already been used to locate the image from the sprite? For example, in the below code, how could i be able to locate the home obtained from the sprite on the desired position in a web page.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  img.home
  {
   width:46px;
   height:44px;
   background:url(img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <img class="home" src="img_trans.gif" width="1" height="1" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

where, (img_trans.gif) is a transparent image and (img_navsprites.gif) is an image sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the entire element by setting `position: absolute` and setting `top` and `left`.

Comment: So, there is no other way using the properties of a background?